# Magento - Ajax calling PHP not working

Tags: php, ajax, magento, xmlhttprequest

I installed Magento in `local`.
I added my Ajax code in `magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

I'm trying to post some variables to another PHP file in the same location as `view.phtml`.

```
<script>
  function loadXMLDoc()
  {
      var user = "<?php echo $userId;?>";
      var product = "<?php echo $xxx;?>";
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send("userID="+user+"&productID="+product);
      }

      //this is just a countdown timer
     var timeLeft = 3; 
     var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
     timeLeft--;
     var minutesLeft = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
     var secondsLeft = timeLeft % 60;
     console.log('Time left: ' + minutesLeft + ':' + secondsLeft);
     if (timeLeft == 0) {
     window.clearInterval(timer);
     // do some ajax thing

     loadXMLDoc();
         }
     }, 1000);
</script>
```

Basically I will post 2 variables to the test.php after a few seconds.
I'm very sure these codes are working, but when I tried them in the magento product page. 
Its not working. I tried to make sure, if all the code are being executed. 
Everything runs fine, only the Ajax won't post in the PHP files.

In the test.php file, I just get the 2 variables and save it to a .txt file located in the same folder.
The test.php file is for testing purpose only.

All I need is to get the Ajax working. I want it to post to test.php but remain on the same page.

I Google'd around and found some solutions, it seems to have some connection with the Magento controller or something. But I just couldn't understand it.

Can anyone please tell me if there's a simple way to fix this problem?

---

I add this just to make things more clear.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['userID']))
  {   
     $userID = $_POST['userID'];
     $productID = $_POST['productID'];

     $file = "db.txt";

     $current = file_get_contents($file);

     $current .= "\n$userID \t $productID";

     file_put_contents($file, $current);
     }

  ?>
```

and the db.txt is put on the same folder as test.php

How to know if the test.php is being called? 
I tried to check to the db.txt, but nothing changed inside.

---

CORRECTION

I put my test.php and db.txt in the root.
And change

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true)
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/magento/test.php",true)
```

THANK YOU

Comment: are you certain `test.php` exists in your magento root? e.g. `test.php` should exist beside `index.php`

Comment: Hi Jeremi, the test.php is at the same folder as view.phtml. Or should I put the test.php in the root? And I put the txt file on both root and product folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, since you have `test.php` next to view.phtml, that won't work as `xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);` will request a POST on `/test.php` (which means application root).

Please place `test.php` and `db.txt` at the root (same place where you can find Magento's `index.php`)

Comment: Its still not working. I had put both test.php and db.txt on the root same as index.php    I even try to put in the skinURL folder, and try to change post method to get method. Nothing happen. Its just like the xmlhttp.open cant open the file.

Comment: So is it working now? You might want to change `xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);` to `xmlhttp.open("POST","/test.php",true);` (with a leading slash)